# Data dismiss in modal being called twice on click

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've been working a modal which gets dismissed when a user clicks the 'Cancel' button. Everything was working fine until the button developed a bug. When I click on the 'Cancel' button, the modal is dismissed, but closes and opens again. So one needs to click the dismiss button twice to close the modal.

This is the 'Bootstrap' modal and I haven't made any changes to the JS file. Only CSS and HTML have been tinkered with. On inspecting in the browser, I see the following function being called twice.

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

How do I fix this error? I have no idea where to even start! The following is my modal code.

Note: The same error is being encountered with the 'cross' aria label at the top-right corner of the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

                          <div class="modal-content">


                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Why are you deleting this book?</b></h4>
                            </div>

                              <!--modal body starts -->
                              <div class="modal-body">

                                <div class="radio">
                                  <label>
                                      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Sold
                                </div>

                                <div class="radio">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Sold on another site or elsewhere
                                  </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="radio">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Don't want to sell it now
                                  </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="radio">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Lack of buyer interest
                                  </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="radio">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Vacation, break
                                  </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="radio">
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Other reason
                                  </label>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                              <!--modal body end -->

                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                              </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

HTML code for the button which opens up the modal

```
<button type= "submit" class="dashbtn dashbtn-danger">EDIT</button><br>
<button type= "button" class="dashbtn dashbtn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">DELETE</button>
```

Comment: Show me the HTML code on the button

Comment: have you placed the modal html inside the same div where the click to display the modal is handled? if so i imagine the event of the click is bubbling up and there for opening the modal again

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Have updated the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have more than one modal in your code that share the same class. To prevent these type of situations, assign different ids to your modals and use that id in the data-target attribute.
Try this:

```
<button type="submit" class="dashbtn dashbtn-danger">EDIT</button>
<br>
<button type="button" class="dashbtn dashbtn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bs-example-modal-sm">DELETE</button>
```

And for your modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>Why are you deleting this book?</b></h4>
            </div>
            <!--modal body starts -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>Sold
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Sold on another site or elsewhere
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Don't want to sell it now
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Lack of buyer interest
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Vacation, break
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">Other reason
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--modal body end -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just make sure you assign different ids to each modal and trigger each one using `data-target="#foo"`

Look up the section on modal data attributes: [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: what if there are 50+ such modals and they are created in a loop?

Comment: @Neo182, if you're making things in a loop, you can use the loop index to create unique keys for ids; that way you always have unique ids in your DOM.